# Storing and reading data on user account

Tags: web3.js, account-data, api

Is it possible to store user notes in his account or maybe some way around?
Wanna make some kind of on-chain KeePass. Ideally just with web API in React or smth.
Thank you.

Comment: you would need a program (equivalent to "smart contracts") for storing data in accounts. if you're not sure where to start then checkout https://www.soldev.app/course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All data on the blockchain is public! The Memo program can be used to store short sequences of text, but is not suited for encrypted data.

Depending on your use case building a custom contract is most likely the way to go.

MemoSq4gqABAXKb96qnH8TysNcWxMyWCqXgDLGmfcHr

https://spl.solana.com/memo